# How does Backbone View render work?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model's view set up as follows:

```
var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "div.player",
    template: _.template($("#playerTemplate").html()),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

and the main view is set up as follows:

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#players",

    render: function() {
        var pView = new PlayerView({model: playerModel});
        this.$el.append(pView.render().$el);
    }
});
```

If you notice the `render` of `AppView`, I am rendering the `PlayerView`  first, and then appending its `$el` to `AppView`'s $el. I was expecting an error situation here, as it would display `PlayerView` 2 times to main View as follows:

- First, in the `pView.render()` where I put content in `pView` and
- Second, in the same line where I append pView's `$el` to main view.

But it just appends the `pView` only once. How does this work?

I am not sure I have explained my question clearly; I can add more context if required.

Comment: Appending the `PlayerView` element to `AppView` will not cause the content to duplicate itself. You're appending the content to `PlayerView`, then appending the `PlayerView` element (which is the container element + the appended content),  to `AppView`. Also, Backbone's render functionality is entirely defined by you, so it doesn't really "work" in any way, only in the way you define it to. The `el` stuff is still javascript/jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am not sure about following:  My html already contains `div.player`, so when I first append the content in `PlayerView`, it should draw on the screen, right? after that, when I append `PlayerView's`  `el` to `AppView` the whole `PlayerView` should be again drawn on the screen. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I understand your confusion. When an element is appended to another, it is moved from it's original spot. Example. https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/xtenekte/2/

Comment: wow, that is something cool, thanks for explaining it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `div.player` exists in DOM as you mentioned in comments,

When you do `pView.render()`, it adds the template inside it.

Then when you append `pView`'s element (`div.player`) to AppView's element (`#players`), entire `div.player` is moved into `#players`.

Your code is working the way it should work.

If you intent to create multiple players, You shouldn't use `el` option in player view, Instead you should decorate the element created by backbone and create multiple instances of player view.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand what's happening behind the scenes.